# jQuery Sortables without removing from list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists for a media player - the *play queue* and the *library of tunes*. They are both sortable lists and connected. It works great, but dragging from the *library* to the *playlist* (obviously) deletes the tune from the *library* list.

Is there any way to preserve list items in one of the sortable lists?

Comment: detect if you change from playlist when it does `.clone` the element to the new playlist.. you can do where you define the 'drop' event

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623703/clone-node-on-drag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answers to this similar question... Setting up the helper to clone and how the items are copied are what you're going to be looking for... You might have to change a couple of things. For instance, if you want it so you can have multiple of one item from the library in the playlist (the same song more than once), you'll have to modify that top answer, as it disregards duplicates.

[jquery ui sortables connect lists: copy items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916089/jquery-ui-sortables-connect-lists-copy-items)