# how to keep original source list using sortable jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i know this has already been asked here in stackoverflow, but i could not find an exact answer to my problem.

If i have two lists (source and second list). I'd like to copy from the source and drop into the second list, but i want to keep the original items in the source list. Is there a way to do it just using sortable, and not draggable?

i'd really appreciate any help.

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3916089/7469

Comment: I wonder what use case they both had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely aren't using appropriate plugin and would do better with droppable and draggable. There are several ways to set them up, you can use clone helper option on the draggable, so it stays in place and the clone is shown to user, or you set revert to animate it sliding back to original position when dropped.

You would then use the drop event of the droppable to have the draggable appended to it

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert